# ReSharper invalidates coroutines from C++ 20

Tags: c++, resharper, asio

I'm getting started with ASIO C++ 20, which uses the coroutines. It marks  `awaitable`, `co_await` and `use_awaitable` as "Cannot resolve symbol x". I know it's ReSharper because it works fine until ReSharper loads. The code compiled as expected, the problem is the IntelliSense bug that ReSharper causes. How can I fix it?

[image]

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <asio/awaitable.hpp>
#include <asio/detached.hpp>
#include <asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <asio/read_until.hpp>
#include <asio/redirect_error.hpp>
#include <asio/signal_set.hpp>
#include <asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <asio/use_awaitable.hpp>
#include <asio/write.hpp>

using asio::ip::tcp;
using asio::awaitable;
using asio::co_spawn;
using asio::detached;
using asio::redirect_error;
using asio::use_awaitable;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class chat_participant
{
public:
    virtual ~chat_participant() = default;
    virtual void deliver(const std::string& msg) = 0;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<chat_participant> chat_participant_ptr;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class chat_room
{
public:
    void join(chat_participant_ptr participant)
    {
        participants_.insert(participant);
        for (const auto &msg : recent_msgs_)
            participant->deliver(msg);
    }

    void leave(chat_participant_ptr participant)
    {
        participants_.erase(participant);
    }

    void deliver(const std::string& msg)
    {
        recent_msgs_.push_back(msg);
        while (recent_msgs_.size() > max_recent_msgs)
            recent_msgs_.pop_front();

        for (const auto &participant : participants_)
            participant->deliver(msg);
    }

private:
    std::set<chat_participant_ptr> participants_;
    enum { max_recent_msgs = 100 };
    std::deque<std::string> recent_msgs_;
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class chat_session
    : public chat_participant,
    public std::enable_shared_from_this<chat_session>
{
public:
    chat_session(tcp::socket socket, chat_room& room)
        : socket_(std::move(socket)),
        timer_(socket_.get_executor()),
        room_(room)
    {
        timer_.expires_at(std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point::max());
    }

    void start()
    {
        room_.join(shared_from_this());

        co_spawn(socket_.get_executor(),
            [self = shared_from_this()]{ return self->reader(); },
            detached);

        co_spawn(socket_.get_executor(),
            [self = shared_from_this()]{ return self->writer(); },
            detached);
    }

    void deliver(const std::string& msg) override
    {
        write_msgs_.push_back(msg);
        timer_.cancel_one();
    }

private:
    awaitable<void> reader()
    {
        try
        {
            for (std::string read_msg;;)
            {
                std::size_t n = co_await asio::async_read_until(socket_,
                    asio::dynamic_buffer(read_msg, 1024), "\n", use_awaitable);

                room_.deliver(read_msg.substr(0, n));
                read_msg.erase(0, n);
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception&)
        {
            stop();
        }
    }

    awaitable<void> writer()
    {
        try
        {
            while (socket_.is_open())
            {
                if (write_msgs_.empty())
                {
                    asio::error_code ec;
                    co_await timer_.async_wait(redirect_error(use_awaitable, ec));
                }
                else
                {
                    co_await asio::async_write(socket_,
                        asio::buffer(write_msgs_.front()), use_awaitable);
                    write_msgs_.pop_front();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception&)
        {
            stop();
        }
    }

    void stop()
    {
        room_.leave(shared_from_this());
        socket_.close();
        timer_.cancel();
    }

    tcp::socket socket_;
    asio::steady_timer timer_;
    chat_room& room_;
    std::deque<std::string> write_msgs_;
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

awaitable<void> listener(tcp::acceptor acceptor)
{
    chat_room room;

    for (;;)
    {
        std::make_shared<chat_session>(
            co_await acceptor.async_accept(use_awaitable),
            room
            )->start();
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    try
    {
        unsigned short port = 666;

        asio::io_context io_context(1);

        co_spawn(io_context,
            listener(tcp::acceptor(io_context, { tcp::v4(), port })),
            detached);

        asio::signal_set signals(io_context, SIGINT, SIGTERM);
        signals.async_wait([&](auto, auto) { io_context.stop(); });

        io_context.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with R++ and the `_MSC_VER` predefined macro. Boost expects `_MSC_VER` >= 1928 in order for coroutines to be enabled, R++ defines it to 1920 at the moment in its internal preprocessor. This will be fixed in R++ 2021.2. As a workaround, you can add this snippet before the boost includes:

```
#ifdef __RESHARPER__
#define _MSC_VER 1928
#endif
```

Please report other R++ issues to ReSharper support or directly to the [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=%23RSCPP). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I saw you reported it! However, the workaround doesn't work.

Comment: Interesting, it works for me. Could you please create a small project with your code and attach it to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-32066? Which Boost are you using?

Comment: The code above in the question is the whole code and it's not so big. I'm not using the boost ASIO, but the standalone version asio-1.18.1. Download link is from the official site: https://sourceforge.net/projects/asio/files/asio/1.18.1%20%28Stable%29/asio-1.18.1.zip/download